# How can i get an API response status code to highlight v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I am implementing a simple login authentication form using Vuetify (I am really newbie in the use of Vuetify and axios for data consumption). The dummy test API I am using returns 200 response if the `username=password`, 401 response if `username < password` and 404 if `username > password`.

I have already implemented the 404 response status that throws an `ALERT('USER NOT FOUND')` if the error response is 404 and if the response is 200, it redirects me/logs me in to the homepage.

I need to show some comments/highlights(tooltip) in the username and password fields if the error response status code is 401 using vuetify.

```js
methods: {
  /*  errorFn() {
        if (this.username.length < this.password.length) {
          document.getElementById("usepass").style.borderBottomColor = "red";
          return true;
        }
      }, */
  login: function() {
    var bodyFormData = new FormData()
    bodyFormData.set('username', this.username)
    bodyFormData.set('password', this.password)
    bodyFormData.set('client_id', 'WraptiousArtistApp')
    bodyFormData.set(
      'redirect_url',
      'https://dorothy2.wraptious.com/api/v0.1/users/me',
    )
    const headers = {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    }
    if (this.username == '' && this.password == '') {
      this.$v.$touch()
    } else if (this.username != '' && this.password != '') {
      return axios
        .post(URL, bodyFormData, headers)
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .then(() => this.$router.push('/home'))
        .catch(err => {
          // if username < password { highlight comments in username and password fields }
          if (err.response.status == 401) {
            alert(err.response.data.message)
            console.log(err.response)
            /* document.getElementById("userpass").style.borderColor = "red"; 
                this.errorFn();*/
          }
          // if username > password { throw a 404: User not found message }
          if (err.response.status == 404) {
            alert(err.response.data.message)
            console.log(err.response.data.code, 'User not Found')
          }
        })
    }
  },
},
```

```html
<v-form>
    <v-text-field
      :error-messages="usernameError"
      :rules="usernameRules"
      :counter="10"
      required
      label="Username"
      v-model="username"
      name="username"
      prepend-icon="person"
      type="text"
      @input="$v.username.$touch()"
      @blur="$v.username.$touch()"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      :error-messages="passwordError"
      :counter="5"
      required
      v-model="password"
      label="Password"
      name="password"
      prepend-icon="lock"
      type="password"
      @input="$v.password.$touch()"
      @blur="$v.password.$touch()"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you have already defined data properties for displaying text field errors: `passwordError` and `usernameError`. And you pass them through `error-messages` prop, which

> Puts the input in an error state and passes through custom error
>   messages. Will be combined with any validations that occur from the
>   rules prop. This field will not trigger validation

So in your handlers just assign appropriate error to this properties.

```js
if (err.response.status == 401) {
  this.passwordError = 'Your password is invalid :('
}
if (err.response.status == 404) {
  this.usernameError = 'User not found'    
}
```